# reload graphs generated by R packages

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, r-forestplot

Please see the following example: based on `forestplot` package help document:

```
library(forestplot)
# DATA
row_names <- list(list("test = 1", expression(test >= 2)))
test_data <- data.frame(coef=c(1.59, 1.24),
                        low=c(1.4, 0.78),
                        high=c(1.8, 1.55))
# Graph
graph1 <- forestplot(row_names,
           test_data$coef,
           test_data$low,
           test_data$high,
           lineheight = "auto",
           xlab = "Lab axis txt")
```

I got a graph: 
[image]

The graph was also saved as `graph1`. However, when I reloaded `graph1`

```
dev.off()
graph1
```

I got no graph but the following:

```
> graph1 
GRID.VP.34::forestplot_margins
```

I wonder if this is the nature of the package or something wrong with my installation of either `R`, `Rstudio` or other packages on my machine. It appears that I have no such problems with `ggplot2` graphs. Any advice would be appreciated.